# surface integral using substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I am stuck trying to calculate the following surface integral:

$$\int _{R}\int (x+y)^{2}ds$$

over the the following regions:

$$0\leqslant x+2y\leqslant 2\: \: \wedge \: \: 0\leqslant x-y\leqslant 1$$

My professor suggested us to use the following substitutions:

$$u = x -y \: \: \wedge v = x+2y$$

I have done the following in order to find ds

$$\frac{du}{ds}= \frac{dx}{ds}-\frac{dy}{ds} \: \: \wedge \frac{dv}{ds}= \frac{dx}{ds}-2\frac{dy}{ds}
$$
 but it does not work :(

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any diffeomorphism $\phi \colon A \to B$ on open sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$  you get

$$ \int_B f(x,y) \,d(x,y) = \int_A f(\phi(x,y)) \, |det D\phi| \, d(x,y).$$

If you choose

$$A := \{ (x,y) \mid 0 < x +2y < 2 ,\, 0 < x-y < 1 \} $$
$$ \phi(x,y) := (x+2y,x-y)$$
$$B := (0,2) \times (0,1)$$
$$ f(x,y) := \left(\frac{y+2x}{3}\right)^2$$

and calculate $ |det D\phi| = 3$ you obtain
 $$\int_0^1 \int_0^ 2 \left(\frac{y+2x}{3} \right)^2 \frac{1}{3} \,dx \,dy= \int_A (x+y)^2 \, dxdy$$

The only difficulty was to find a function $f$ with $f(\phi(x,y)) = (x+y)^2$.

Note that $A$ and your set $R$ only differ in a zero set.

Comment: The sets $A$ and $B$ must be open, otherwise the jacobian is in general not always $ \neq 0$, but since the integral on the boundary of A is $0$ it does not change anything to the final value, the only thing is that it is theoretically incorrect, but all the rest is true (+1). If you want i evaluated the final value of the integral that is 

$$\int_0^1\int_0^2 \left( \dfrac{2y+x}{3}\right)^2\frac13 dx dy = \frac{28}{81}$$

Comment: @Ale if the jacobian is zero or not has nothing to do with choosing a open or closed set. But your right, usually this theorem holds only for open set because a diffeomorphism is  definied on a open set. I will note that in the answer.

Comment: In this case it has nothing to do, but consider the polar coordinate transformation. The Jacobian is $r$ and there you need to take the value of $r$ to be in $(0,\infty)$ because if you were integrating over $[0,\infty]$ The jacobian would be $0$ for $r=0$ and then you wouldn't be able to apply the change of variables because the transformation is no more a diffeomorphism :D. However good job. I think that this answer is complete and will really help the OP.

Comment: @Ale why do you require that the determinant of the jacobian should be unequal to 0?

Comment: Because $\phi$ is supposed to be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and it is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism if it is differentiable and its inverse is differentiable, but if the Jacobian is $0$ there does not exist an inverse function of $\phi$

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use the transformation $u = x-y$ and $v=x+2y$, the problem is reduced to evaluate $$\int_0^1\int_0^2 \left(\frac{2u+v}{3}\right)^2\frac{1}{3}dudv$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be (according to your transformations)

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^2\left(\dfrac{2u+v}{3}\right)^2 \frac13 dvdu$$

Comment: @Ale yeah.. thanks

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam actually I think that u+2v was correct in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leqslant x+2y\leqslant 2\: \: \wedge \: \: 0\leqslant x-y\leqslant 1 \iff 0\leqslant x\leqslant \frac43\: \: \wedge \: \: \frac{-x}{2}\leqslant y\leqslant 1+\frac{-x}{2}$$
so first integrate along $y$ like $x$ was a constant and then integrate along $x$.

Comment: I think it should be 4/3 instead of 3/4

Comment: @Adam, Thanks for the fix ;)

Comment: I can't find out how did you arrive to this solution, i always have problem in solving this kind of things, could you please write down one more step?

Comment: You multiply by two the second equation and you add the first and the new second to find boundaries for x. Therefore, you use the first one to find boundaries for y.